# XCode 4 is hiding the results from Find operation

Tags: xcode4, find

Please take a look at this:

[image]

It says 'Found 6 results in 3 files', but how can I see which files are those and the exact line, you know the usual way.
I've haven't set any options or settings anywhere, its just all default settings.
This is making me crazy!

Comment: Sounds like an xCode 4 bug. Probably the wrong place to ask. You should report the bug to Apple.

Comment: Did you try to quit and restart xCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for taking interest in it, but I think I found the answer. Its as dumb as the question.

There is another field to filter the result at bottom and when I cleaned it I got everything back to normal :)

[image]

Hope this saves somebody hours.